# init method with annotation PostConstruct create error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I wrote a method 'init' with annotation PostConstruct

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BrandController {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{carsService}")
private CarsService carsService;
private String name;
private String country;
private List<Brand> listBrands;

public BrandController() {
}

public void setListBrands(List<Brand> listBrands) {
    this.listBrands = listBrands;
}
@PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        setListBrands(carsService.listBrand());
    }

    //here is all setters and getters
}
```

I have also

```
public interface CarsService 
{
public void createBrand(Brand b);
public void deleteBrand(Brand b);
public List<Brand> listBrand();
}
```

and implementation for this interface

```
@Service("carsService")
@Transactional
public class CarSeviceImpl implements CarsService{
@Autowired
private BrandDao branDao;

public BrandDao getBranDao() {
    return branDao;
}

public void setBranDao(BrandDao branDao) {
    this.branDao = branDao;
}

@Override
public List<Brand> listBrand()
{
    return branDao.listBrand();
}

@Override
public void createBrand(Brand b) {
    branDao.createBrand(b);
}

@Override
public void deleteBrand(Brand b) {
    branDao.deleteBrand(b);
}


}
```

my brand.xhtml view:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>brands</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="formBrands">
        <p:growl/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2"  cellpadding="6">
            <p:outputLabel value="Name" for="nameIn"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{brandController.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="the input field name is empty" id="nameIn"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Coutry" for="countryIn"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{brandController.country}" required="true" requiredMessage="the input field coutry is empty" id="countryIn"/>
            <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{brandController.save}" update=":formBrands :formList"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="formList">
        <p:dataTable id="brandTable" value="#{brandController.listBrands}" var="brand" rowKey="#{brand.name}" rows="10"
                     emptyMessage="there is no brands" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom">
            <p:column headerText="name">
                <h:outputText value="#{brand.name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="country">
                <h:outputText value="#{brand.country}"/>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

I`m getting error like this '

> An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean
>   brandController

' when I try run my webapp with brand view...

Could you tell me where I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: Spring services cannot be injected using `@ManagedProperty` into JSF managed beans. You will need Spring (or CDI) managed beans using Spring related annotations like `@Autowired` (or CDI `@Inject`).

Comment: @Tiny you can perfectly well use `@ManagedProperty` to inject beans, given that you have correctly added the `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` to the `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: You also need to provide setter for `@ManagedProperty`. I can't see it in your listing.